# Removing frequency from signal with fft

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency

I'm doing the fft to remove a certain frequency from a sound file.

The thing is that maybe I'm blind or what but somehow I managed to remove only the frequency from one side, while the other doesn't go away even if I zero it out. Could someone tell me if my indexes are wrongly used?

Here is my code:

```matlab
[frase, fs] = audioread('frase.wav');
soundsc(frase, fs);
S_fft = fft(frase);
N = length(frase);
F = (0:(N-1))/N*fs;
figure, plot(F, abs(S_fft));

% Remove the ugly frequency
S = S_fft;
zero = zeros(size(S));
S(200:400) = zero(200:400);
S(end-2*310:end-310) = zero(end-2*310:end-310);
figure, plot(F, abs(S));
```

And here the resulting spectrum:

[image: So the peak, in the beginning, isn't going anywhere]

Comment: Maybe, but I don't really understand why I manage to remove the peak on the right but not the other in the left then D:

Comment: Please upload the sound file to properly reconstruct the error.  Also, declaring a `zero` array to represent an array of zeros is superfluous.  For example, you can just do `S(200:400) = 0;`.  However, I suspect you aren't zeroing out the right frequencies.  The right frequency goes from -620 to -310 from the end.  Therefore, you should really be doing `S(310:620) = 0;` to be consistent with zeroing out the frequencies on the left side to be symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

*I don't have your* `frase.wav` *file, so I made myself one with two frequencies, 5 kHz and 15 kHz at a sample rate of 44100 Hz. I consider 15 kHs is the "ugly one", the one I want to remove.*

I think you confused the frequencies you want to remove with the indexes of these frequencies.

Here is a suggested fix, using `find` fo find the indexes of the frequency I want to remove.

```
[frase, fs] = audioread('frase.wav');
soundsc(frase, fs);
S_fft= fft(frase);
N = length(frase);
F = (0:(N-1))/N*fs;
subplot(2, 1, 1); plot(F, abs(S_fft)); title('Before');

%% Identify Ugly Frequency
Fu = 15000;

%% Remove the Ugly Frequency
tol = 10; % Tolerance around the ugly frequency
indexes_p = find(F>Fu-tol & F<Fu+tol); % Find indexes of ugly frequency
indexes_n = find(F>(fs-Fu)-tol & F<(fs-Fu));
indexes = [indexes_p indexes_n];
S_fft(indexes) = 0;
subplot(2, 1, 2); plot(F, abs(S_fft)); title('After');
```

The result is

[image: remove frequency]